# Swift - CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. UITextView & iAd

Tags: matrix, swift, uitextview, iad, singular

I have View Controller with UITextView and in the bottom I have iAds.

When I access the View Controller I get an error: `<Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.`  Why?

Everything works fine, but when I change from Portrait to Landscape or vice-versa I get this error twice.

Maybe something is wrong with the UITextView and the iAds?

Comment: This happens only when you import iAds

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: No, even the last XCode GM seed don't clear the error...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `CGPostError`.  When it's hit, type `bt` in the debug console.  Copy the stack trace and paste it into your question.

Comment: @robmayoff having similar issue, stacktraces are http://pastebin.com/eZqh0kGs and http://pastebin.com/X5VnxM7p Looks like it happens when test ads are not working - otherwise everything is ok. Not related to swift though - I'm using objectve-c with xcode6+ios8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely ok. Dont worry about this. That's Xcode trouble. iAd would working fine in production.